# How to type hint a Python module

Tags: python, python-typing

I have this Python module which is very handy:

```py
# src/payment_settings.py
from utils.payment import get_current_payment_settings


def __getattr__(name):
    settings = get_current_payment_settings()
    return getattr(settings, name)


def __setattr__(name):
    raise NotImplementedError("payment_settings is read-only")
```

I use it like a special cached, read-only variable like this:

```py
# src/another_file.py
from . import payment_settings

print(payment_settings.something)
```

I want to globally type hint it with the type returned by `get_current_payment_settings()`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This looks like bad design. Why can't you implement `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` on the class of `settings` and use that instead?

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite impressed by the `__getattr__`/`__setattr__` workaround you have here, but I think it's worth considering other options that will allow for more advanced type hinting. In general, it's better to store things in classes, and by doing this your type hint issue will also resolve itself. Consider the below:

### Using @property

```py
class PaymentSettings:
    @property
    def something(self) -> int:
        return 1
```

Here by defining a property getter without a setter, `something` is made read-only and given a type.

### Using a frozen dataclass

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class _PaymentSettings:
    something: int = 1

PaymentSettings = _PaymentSettings()
```

Dataclasses are also a reasonable way of storing structured immutable data using the frozen parameter.

### [Pydantic](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic)

If you're looking for a more nested settings layout, it may also be worth considering using Pydantic, as this offers ways to easily create immutable storage: *[frozen instance-attribute](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict.frozen)*

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict

class BaseImmutable(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(frozen=True)

class Nested(BaseImmutable):
    attr: int = 1

class _PaymentSettings(BaseImmutable):
    something: Nested = Nested()


PaymentSettings = _PaymentSettings()
```